# Use existing subpanel for EV Charger

Tags: electrical-panel, circuit-breaker

I would like to install an EV Charger (Juicebox 32, 32A / 7.7 kW) in my garage.
In the garage we do have an existing sub-panel, however the panel seems to be full (see picture ). [image]

The main breaker is outside of the house and there is another panel in the house.

The question I have is, that on the "main panel" in the house is a 60A, 2 Pole 220V breaker that is connected to my electric oven - when I flip the breaker, the oven is off. The same thing happens, when I flip the breaker on the sub-panel in the garage (50A, 2 Pole 220V) - it's connected to the oven and it turns the oven off.

Can I remove the 50A breaker in the garage sub-panel and "hardwire" the oven circuit?
After that I'd like to use the free spot for a 40A breaker for the EV charger.

Side question: Why came someone up with the idea of adding two breakers two one circuit?
Thank you very much!

[image]

Comment: This is very confusing. It is extremely unlikely that there is an "oven breaker" in two different panels. More likely is that the breaker in one panel is the *feed breaker* to the other panel, and the breaker in that other panel (subpanel, by definition) is the actual "oven breaker". So need to turn only one "oven breaker" off and see what is affected, if anything, besides the oven.

Comment: Thanks for your quick feedback! Nothing else happens besides the fact that the oven turns off (if i flip the 60amp breaker, everything in the garage is still working) - it is really confusing for me as well :D

Comment: It is confusing, I only see 1 garage outlets on that panel can a 60 amp push that panel sure, pull the dead face off and provide a pic of the wiring I believe manassehkatz is right

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Is there no model/listing labeling anywhere on the garage subpanel?

Comment: @EdBeal i'd like to get rid of the 50amp breaker in the garage and have the breaker for the EV charger there instead. i'll provide a picture of the inside of the garage sub-pabel asap

Comment: @max, it is likely the 60 amp breaker from the main is powering the sub. It also looks like the tape is covering a open slot, your path forward may be to put in a quad breaker, all the slots look to be approved for tandems, a quad 20/40-40/20 would give you a spare 20 and the 40 you want. It looks like a mix of breaker brands in the panel already and that ends up being common with these older panels, if you can post a clear photo of the sub with its dead face off we could give better advice.